# CSS active is not working for selecting the tabs

Tags: html, css

Once we select the any tabs like account,bills,data,usage.Hovering working perfect.
But selected backgroundcolor is not active state,
Here is my css

```
.header :active, .footer:active {
    border: none;
    background:yellow;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #777;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64Jba/)

Comment: remove the space between header and :active

Comment: `.header :active` !== `.header:active`.

Comment: The `:active` pseudo selector only applies while the link is active. Once the action the link starts is completed, it is no longer considered active. I think what you really want here is an active class that you add to the tabs when they are selected, and remove when they are not.

Comment: Read dpk2442 comment. Give us the clear requirement.

Comment: I have different tabs, once hovering background color will be changes it is fine,now the requirement is once we click the tab >> background color should be changed andbackgorund color remain changed until we click on another tab. Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/64Jba/

Answer (score 2):

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/64Jba/1/)

you should remove the space between `header` and `:active`

```
.header:active, .footer:active {
    border: none;
    background:yellow;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #777;
}
```